# Why wasn't the theory that light's velocity depended on its source very popular?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, speed-of-light, velocity, history, relative-motion

Before special relativity, it was believed that light having a specific velocity meant it had to travel through something. My question is, why wasn't the idea that light depended on its source very popular? This seem to solve a lot of the problems they were having. Was it disproved early on? (I was having trouble finding any experiments related to this).

The reason why I ask is I was explaining the history of relativity to someone, and they proposed that light's velocity could depend on its source (I was at the Maxwell's laws part, before special relativity). I said this was false, but didn't have a reason.

How did we know that light's velocity didn't depend on its source?

Comment: By "depend on its source", do you mean that the idea was that you could add some velocity to the velocity of the source to get the velocity of the emitted light (all in the same reference frame)?

Comment: @HDE226868 Yes. Specifically, light would move light speed only in the reference frame of its source. It works for things like bullets. I am in particular asking why *aether* theory was more popular than this one.

Comment: @brucesmitherson That is the opposite of the answer I was looking for.

Comment: This question clearly belongs into history of science rather than physics.

Comment: I think Asher's answer addresses the velocity from the moving source.  The real puzzle at the time was the expected change in velocity from the point of view of the observer (the Earth - which, as we know, moves).  That was predicted to add to or subtract from the speed of light but it wasn't observed in tests and that was the really confusing part.

Answer (score 3):

Before special relativity, we already knew from other experiments that light is a wave; we can diffract, refract and reflect light like any other wave. And we knew from observation that waves behave in certain particular manners: that they travel with a fixed speed based on their medium, regardless of the velocity of the source.

When it comes to modeling velocity, additive velocities work for particles and fixed speeds work for waves. We didn't have any examples of particles with fixed speeds, or waves with additive velocities, so the discovery that light is a wave precluded theoretically the notion that it had a variable speed. It wouldn't fit with the observations of other waves we understood quite well. So the picture of light as a particle being 'thrown out' ahead of the source lost favor while the fixed-speed wave theory gained favor.

Comment: Okay, so it was because we saw it as a wave that we assumed it would follow a fixed-speed. (It's ironic how that we also found out light acting like a wave is weird in quantum mechanics as well. I feel like its symbolic of something).

Answer (score 0):

You can answer it just fine when you have Maxwell's Equation.

If there is at least one frame in which Maxwell's Equation holds then in the charge free current free region between a source and a receiver then light, as electromagnetic fields, travels at speed $c$ a constant determine by $\epsilon_0$ and $\mu_0$.

So the wave is only allowed to go at that speed by Maxwell. No matter what the source does the charge free current free region has to satisfy Maxwell so had to have the light travel at speed $c$.

If necessary you might have to appeal to uniqueness of solutions to Maxwell.

The reason you get relativity is simply by insisting that they travel at this same speed for a whole bunch of frames. But just one frame is enough to get that the speed of light doesn't depend on the motion of the source.